# Wave equation on infinite line with piecewise $2\pi$-periodic i.c.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, periodic-functions, wave-equation, piecewise-continuity

---

Just to be clear, the fact that the function $g$ is periodic is throwing me off as to how I even *integrate* it. I'm probably overthinking - I guarantee you it's that, and not that I don't know how to find integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you have  $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2a}(G(x+at)-G(x-at)$ where $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$. A periodic function whose integral over its period is $0$ has a periodic antiderivative. In this case, it's $|x|$ restricted to $[-\pi,\pi]$ and extended periodically. There are various ways to express this function in a formula, for example  $G(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, 2\pi \mathbb{Z})$ which means the distance from $x$ to the nearest element of the set $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$.